# Trying to move an object and using Tkinter as a GUI, but it is not working when there is more than one instance of the class

Tags: python, tkinter

Well, I never really worked in Python before this project. I am doing it because it's an assignment from a teacher (even tough we never had a Python class) and, of course, because learning a new language is always good.

Anyways this code is working as intended until I add another instance of the `AND` class. When I add it in my code things are going crazy. I would appreciate if you would check how my code works with and without both test instances of the `AND` class. While we are at it I would really appreciate if one of you guys/girls could tell me how to make the `AND` button create a new instance of the class (for example in c++ I would use new `AND`, I want something similar when I press the button).

EDIT: As someone pointed i was not clear enough. What i meant by things go crazy
is that when i add more than 1 instance of the class the click and drag function i'm trying to do is not working properly anymore. The click and drag is not working anymore for one square and for the other one it will just follow my mouse whenever i go around it, even tought i'm not clicking. I really belive that this is because i have this int the **init** function :

```
   self.workspace.tag_bind(self.patrat,"<Enter>",self.whileInside)
   workspace.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.onRelease)
```

I think it doesn't belong there but i really have no ideea how to desing my code and where to put this, if that's the problem

Here's my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*

def doNothing():
    print("nothing happens bro")

root = Tk()

#========= Drop down menu/toolbar
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="file", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New Project...",command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="New",command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="exit",command=doNothing)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="edit", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="redo", command=doNothing)

#========Canvas
workspace=tk.Canvas(root, width=740, height=540,bg="white")
workspace.grid(row=0,column=1)

#====DRAW FUNCTIONS
# Draw rectangle
class AND():

    def __init__(self):
       x=10
       y=10
       self.workspace=workspace
       self.patrat = workspace.create_rectangle(x , y , x + 40 , y + 40,fill = "blue")
       self.workspace.tag_bind(self.patrat,"<Enter>",self.whileInside)
       print("self.workspace.tag_bind(self.patrat,<Enter>,self.whileInside)")
       workspace.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.onRelease)
       print("  workspace.bind(<ButtonRelease-1>,self.onRelease)")

    def whileInside(self,event):
        self.workspace.tag_bind(self.patrat,"<Button-1>",self.onClick)
        print("self.workspace.tag_bind(self.patrat,<Button-1>,self.onClick)")

    def onClick(self,event):
        self.workspace.tag_bind(self.patrat,"<Motion>", self.callback)
        print("self.workspace.tag_bind(self.patrat,<Motion>, self.callback)")

    def onRelease(self,event):
        self.workspace.tag_unbind(self.patrat,"<Enter>")
        print(" self.workspace.tag_unbind(self.patrat,<Enter>)")
        self.workspace.tag_unbind(self.patrat,"<Button-1>")
        print("self.workspace.tag_unbind(self.patrat,<Button-1>)")
        self.workspace.tag_unbind(self.patrat,"<Motion>")
        print(" self.workspace.tag_unbind(self.patrat,<Motion>)")

    def callback(self,event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        self.workspace.coords(self.patrat, x, y, x + 40, y + 40)


test=AND()
test2=AND()

#========Left Frame
frame= Frame(root)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "n")

leftButton1 = Button(frame,text = "AND",width = 10).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
leftButton2 = Button(frame,text = "OR",width = 10).grid(row = 2, column = 0)
leftButton3 = Button(frame,text = "XOR",width = 10).grid(row = 3, column = 0)
leftButton4 = Button(frame,text = "XNOR",width = 10).grid(row = 4, column = 0)
leftButton5 = Button(frame,text = "NOT",width = 10).grid(row = 5, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "things are going crazy" mean? Stackoverflow isn't a free debugging service. You need to provide a detailed description of how what you're getting is different than what you expect.

Comment: It worked fine for me (running Python 3.6.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `bind` command (not `tag_bind`) does not add a command, it *replaces* a command. So when your second instance calls `workspace.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.onRelease)`, it removes that from the first instance. To add a command you need the optional 3rd argument, like this: `workspace.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.onRelease, '+')`

However, there's a much easier way to accomplish what you want. The event also includes information about the mouse buttons. So just bind to motion permanently and check the mouse button before moving:

```
class AND():
    def __init__(self):
        x=10
        y=10
        self.workspace=workspace
        self.patrat = workspace.create_rectangle(x , y , x + 40 , y + 40,fill = "blue")
        self.workspace.tag_bind(self.patrat,"<Motion>",self.on_motion)

    def on_motion(self, event):
        if event.state & 256: # if the left mouse button is down
            x, y = event.x, event.y
            self.workspace.coords(self.patrat, x, y, x + 40, y + 40)
```

Comment: I found your answer very helpful. I tried searching the internet to get more info on event states, i want to do something similar but only when i press right click. I mean this instruction "if event.state & 256",i really want to know more about that 256 code and what does it mean, and also where i can learn more codes like that

Comment: @StanciuVlad The 256 is a [bitmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_\(computing\)#Uses_of_bitmasks). If you are not used to them it would help to write that line in binary: `if event.state & 0b000100000000`. It's checking if the 9th bit (from the right) is a 1 or 0, since Tk sets the 9th bit to 1 when the left mouse button is down and 0 when the left mouse button is up.

Comment: @StanciuVlad  [Here's a list of modifiers](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-handlers.html) (you'll have to convert the masks from hex). It's probably easier to just add `print("{:0>12b}".format(event.state))` to the on_motion function and play with it to see what bit the various mouse buttons and modifier keys (Shift, Alt, etc) set.

Comment: @StanciuVlad the right mouse button sets the 11th bit, so your mask would be: `if event.state & 0b010000000000:`